# What caused the UnicodeDecodeError when I open/read a jpeg file

Tags: python-3.7

I am trying to compress some large jpegs for my website. Installed pyguetzli 1.0.8 successfully, with python 3.7.   But I got UnicodeDecodeError when I read a jpg.  What caused this error and how do I resolve it?

```py
>>> input_jpg = open("/home/chariya/python/images/backup/Dendrobium_anilii_4.jpg").read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I couldn't find any thin in documentation that discuss this error.  Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.  Apparently I need to open the file in binary mode.